# AutoHotkey v2 "Nonexistent hotkey" when disabling hotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I'm having trouble figuring out how to disable key remappings in AutoHotkey v2. Just to provide a simple test for reproducing the problem, here I map `F11` to `Home` (which works), and then I try to disable it:

```
F11::Home
Hotkey "F11", "Off"
```

AutoHotkey tells me:

> Error: Nonexistent hotkey.
>
> Specifically: F11

(The error message points to the `Hotkey "F11", "Off"` line.)

I'm just following the [remap documentation for v2](https://lexikos.github.io/v2/docs/misc/Remap.htm), which clearly says:

> When a script is launched, each remapping is translated into a pair of hotkeys. For example, a script containing `a::b` actually contains the following two hotkeys instead:
>
> ```
> *a::
> {
>     SetKeyDelay -1
>     Send "{Blind}{b DownR}"
> }
>
> *a up::
> {
>     SetKeyDelay -1
>     Send "{Blind}{b Up}"
> }
> ```

It then goes on to say:

> Since remappings are translated into hotkeys as described above, the Suspend function affects them. Similarly, the Hotkey function can disable or modify a remapping. For example, the following two functions would disable the remapping `a::b`.
>
> ```
> Hotkey "*a", "Off"
> Hotkey "*a up", "Off"
> ```

That seems exactly what I'm doing here. Is this an AutoHotkey v2 bug?

On a related note, once I get this working, do I need to disable/enable the implicit "up" hotkey as well when I toggle a short-form hotkey assignment, like this?

```
Hotkey "F11", "Off"
Hotkey "F11 up", "Off"
…
Hotkey "F11", "On"
Hotkey "F11 up", "On"
```

Or do I simply need to toggle the key itself and the "up" key will get toggled automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, it appears the mistake was mine, missing the tiny detail in the [documentation](https://lexikos.github.io/v2/docs/misc/Remap.htm) that a `*` is added to the hotkey names, which [represents](https://lexikos.github.io/v2/docs/Hotkeys.htm) a wildcard. Thus my code should be:

```
F11::Home
Hotkey "*F11", "Off"
```

That seems to work. I'm still in doubt about whether I need to toggle just `"*F11"` or both `"*F11"` and `"*F11 up"`, though.

Comment: "the following two functions would disable the remapping a::b" - makes me think that if you run one of the two functions, it will disable the mapping completely (so no need to run both).  But you'd have to test that I suppose!